# delete duplicate elements in linked list

Tags: c, pointers, duplicates, singly-linked-list

I have a list:
  
1-2-3-3-4-5-6-6-2-7-8-6-9-10-9-NULL //Before
I wnt to make it as following:
      1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-NULL //After
I have written following code:

```
void don(struct node *head)
{
struct node *t,*p,*q;
t=head;
p=t->next;//p is to check each node!
q=t;//q is used to take care of previous node!
while(p!=NULL)
{
    if(p->data==t->data)
    {
        while(p->data==t->data)
        {
            p=p->next;
        }
        q->next=p;
        q=q->next;

    }
    else
    {
        p=p->next;
        q=q->next;
    }
}
t=t->next;
if(t!=NULL)
    don(t);
}
```

But the output is :
1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-6-9-10

Please tell me what is wrong in the code and please correct it :).

Comment: One thing wrong is that you are leaking memory.

Comment: It looks like you're only checking for adjacent duplicates.

Comment: you're only skipping consecutive dupes

Comment: Code is *not* comparing adjacent nodes; it is comparing each node to the first (`t` doesn't change until *after* the `while` loop).

Comment: @Pranav Saxena  Is it a singly-linked list?

Comment: @ScottHunter the while condition compares adjacent nodes, moves to the next if the same, loop ends when different, outer loop moves on.

Comment: Granted, not the most elegant logic ... suggest what so many others suggest to newbie coders - draw the picture first!

Comment: @CarlH sir how to draw the picture. I mean i am not able to understand meaning of drawing picture

Comment: @PranavSaxena - I'm not talking about writing code - what I mean is get a whiteboard or pencil and paper, draw the linked list, and work through your logic visually.  Your code will be an embodiment of how you do it on paper.

Comment: @CarlH: That might be the code's intent, but that is not what it is doing, for reasons I explained in my original comment: it is comparing the `data` for `p` and `t`, but `t` never changes within the main `while` loop.

Comment: @ScottHunter: t=t->next before the recursive call, then the new t in the new stack frame is set to the t that was passed in as head.

Comment: @CarlH: True but irrelevant: in every call, `p` starts as `t->next`, and `p` changes while `t` does not, so the code is *not* only comparing adjacent nodes.

Comment: @ScottHunter: that's right, I was a little sloppy in my description - it is only removing adjacent duplicates.  It compares nodes only as long as their data matches, then stops, so duplicates further down the line don't get compared.  I was considering that as adjacent, since as each adjacent node is removed the next one becomes adjacent.  Fine detail but you are correct.

Comment: And while we're thrashing through spaghetti logic someone else just writes the code ...

Comment: @CarlH: Once p changes in the outer loop when the data do not match, then comparisons are no longer being made between adjacent nodes, even by your weirdly expanded definition of "adjacent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function (without testing)

```
void don( struct node *head )
{
    for ( struct node *first = head; first != NULL; first = first->next )
    {
        for ( struct node *current = first; current->next != NULL; )
        {
            if ( current->next->data == first->data )
            {
                struct node *tmp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                free( tmp );
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for your function then even the beginning of the function is wrong

```
void don(struct node *head)
{
struct node *t,*p,*q;
t=head;
p=t->next;//p is to check each node!
//...
```

In general `head` can be equal to `NULL` In this case this statement `p=t->next;` results in undefined behaviour.

EDIT: If the function must be recursive then it can look the following way

```
void don( struct node *head )
{
    if ( head )
    {
        for ( struct node *current = head; current->next != NULL; )
        {
            if ( current->next->data == head->data )
            {
                struct node *tmp = current->next;
                current->next = current->next->next;
                free( tmp );
            }
            else
            {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }

        don( head->next );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a nested while:

```
p= head;
while(p)
{
    q=p->next;
    while(q)
    {
        if (p->data==q->data)
            ...  //remove
        q= q->next;
    }
    p= p->next;
}
```